Extract numerical literal type from `number` data type
The following type type A = Extract<number, 1> returns never in TypeScript v5.5.2.
I would expect it to return 1.
Is that a bug or a feature?

The Extract<T, U> utility type is used to extract all union members from T that are assignable to U. This is what the type definition looks like:
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;

You are expecting number to be assignable to 1. Actually the opposite is the case.
type A = Extract<number, 1>;
//   ^? never

The Extract type is what's known as a distributive conditional type. A conditional type becomes distributive, when used with a generic parameter. Then, the condition applies to each union member. E. g. Extract<1 | 2 | 3, 1> becomes (1 extends 1 ? 1 : never) | (2 extends 1 ? 1 : never) | (3 extends 1 ? 1 : never). However, number is not a union, it's a primitive. So, there's no distribution.
Therefore, if you want extract 1 from number for whatever reason, do this:
type B = Extract<1, number>;
//   ^? 1

TypeScript Playground

Thanks for the very comprehensive answer, that is exactly what I was looking for :)

It shouldn't be a bug.
the Extract<T, U> utility type constructs a type by extracting from T all union members that are assignable to U.
You are trying to extract the type 1 from the type number. However, number represents all possible numeric values in TypeScript, while 1 is a specific numeric literal type. Since 1 is not a union member of number, the Extract utility type will not find any match and therefore returns never.
If you want to get the type 1 from a union that includes 1, you would need to define the union explicitly:
type NumericUnion = 1 | 2 | 3;
type A = Extract<NumericUnion, 1>; // This will correctly result in type 1


Hi @huan, thanks for taking the time to write that. This does seem like a bug or at least a limitation, as it seems like the intended behaviour would be to return 1, but the actual one is returning never due to number not being a Union.

Maybe, there are some scenarios where TypeScript's type inference may not produce the desired result. Like let data = JSON.parse('{"name":"John"}');  will return any as the type. I just try to understand in their way :p. Maybe you can check if there is an issue in the GitHub.
